# configure: error: utf8_mime2text() has new signature, but U8T_CANONICAL is missing

Tags: php, macos

Today I am trying to upgrade php on MacOS Mountain Lion. I followed [MacTuts+](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/server/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion/) tutorial and on the step where I execute that long command:

```bash
./configure  \
--prefix=/usr  \
--mandir=/usr/share/man  \
--infodir=/usr/share/info  \
--sysconfdir=/private/etc  \
--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs  \
--enable-cli  \
--with-config-file-path=/etc  \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr  \
--with-openssl=/usr  \
--with-kerberos=/usr  \
--with-zlib=/usr  \
--enable-bcmath  \
--with-bz2=/usr  \
--enable-calendar  \
--with-curl=/usr  \
--enable-dba  \
--enable-exif  \
--enable-ftp  \
--with-gd  \
--enable-gd-native-ttf  \
--with-icu-dir=/usr  \
--with-iodbc=/usr  \
--with-ldap=/usr  \
--with-ldap-sasl=/usr  \
--with-libedit=/usr  \
--enable-mbstring  \
--enable-mbregex  \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd  \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd  \
--without-pear  \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd  \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock  \
--with-readline=/usr  \
--enable-shmop  \
--with-snmp=/usr  \
--enable-soap  \
--enable-sockets  \
--enable-sysvmsg  \
--enable-sysvsem  \
--enable-sysvshm  \
--with-tidy  \
--enable-wddx  \
--with-xmlrpc  \
--with-iconv-dir=/usr  \
--with-xsl=/usr  \
--enable-zip  \
--with-imap=/usr/local/imap-2007 \
--with-kerberos \
--with-imap-ssl \
--enable-intl \
--with-pcre-regex  \
--with-pgsql=/usr  \
--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/X11 \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr  \
--with-png-dir=/usr/X11
```

I get the error at the end of process.

> configure: error: utf8_mime2text() has new signature, but U8T_CANONICAL is missing. This should not happen. Check config.log for additional information.

Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 97):

For those who have the same error on docker:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl \
    && docker-php-ext-install imap
```

Comment: Perfect solution for docker, although I missed the `rm` at the end initially. That messed up the rest of the apt-get statements in my `Dockerfile` :)

Comment: When building for docker, I get `configure: error: OpenSSL libraries not found.` Tried to install libssl-dev with apt, but did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 18):

If you have the 'libc-client-devel' RPM or other package in your OS repository then install it.

This will provide the c-client library and header files which PHP needs for IMAP support.

Comment: The OP was on a Mac, so this doesn't work for him/her - but it worked for me on a Redhat-like (Sci. Linux) system.

Comment: In case of Debian it would be `apt-get install libc-client2007e-dev`

Comment: thanks this worked on ubuntu: apt-get install libc-client2007e-dev

Comment: on centos 7: `yum install epel-release ; yum install uw-imap-devel libc-client` and then configure with `--with-libdir=lib64 --with-imap`

Answer (score 11):

the error can be fixed by removing the IMAP support, removing these lines

```
--with-imap=/usr/local/imap-2007
--with-imap-ssl
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better solution to just install required libraries, instead of removing the service causing the issue? As per _kervin_'s comment below, on RedHat install `libc-client-devel`, or `libc-client2007e-dev` on Ubuntu/Debian, and everything should be fine.

Comment: @MaciejZgadzaj Fredy writes _can be fixed_ and it is another way how to fix this issue. I am compiling my own PHP version 7.2.* and my project does **NOT** need `imap` at all so I could very easy fix this issue. +1 for the answer!

Answer (score 9):

Old threads never die ...

I'm on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5, and have installed my own php, currently 5.6.1, and want to upgrade to 5.6.13 - came across that same error just following imap.

Saw this thread, and ran `brew install imap-uw` then ran `configure` based on my existing `phpinfo` output.

```bash
./configure \
--prefix=/usr/local/php5 \
--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs \
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php5/php.d \
--with-openssl=/usr \
--with-zlib=/usr \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--with-gd \
--with-ldap \
--with-xmlrpc \
--enable-exif \
--enable-soap \
--enable-wddx \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-sockets \
--with-bz2=/usr \
--enable-zip \
--enable-shmop \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--with-mhash \
--enable-fpm \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-dtrace \
--enable-opcache \
--disable-phpdbg \
--with-icu-dir=/usr/local/php5 \
--with-mssql=shared,/usr/local/php5 \
--with-pdo-dblib=shared,/usr/local/php5 \
--with-libxml-dir=shared,/usr/local/php5 \
--with-xsl=shared,/usr/local/php5 \
--with-imap=shared,/usr/local/Cellar/imap-uw/2007f \
--with-kerberos=/usr \
--with-imap-ssl=/usr \
--with-gettext=/usr/local/php5 \
--with-curl=shared,/usr/local/php5 \
--with-png-dir=/usr/local/php5 \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/php5 \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/php5 \
--with-pgsql=shared,/usr/local/php5 \
--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr/local/php5 \
--with-mcrypt=shared,/usr/local/php5 \
--with-tidy=/usr/local/php5 \
--with-gmp=shared,/usr/local/php5 \
--with-readline=shared,/usr/local/php5
```

Then `make`. And it seems to be working fine.

Comment: I believe it should be brew install imap-uw

Answer (score 8):

Docker and PHP with Apache (php:apache default image) can works with:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl && apt-get clean
```

Other dependencies can be needed, depending on the installation.

Comment: [the importance of installing dependency libc-client-dev](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/imap.requirements.php)

Answer (score 5):

This exact same problem came up for me on Fedora when trying to compile PHP 5.5.0.

The problem is related to the `'--with-imap'` configuration parameter.

In order to solve this problem I compiled my own version of imap from the latest source (currently imap-2007f) and to do that I had to install some prerequisites. On fedora I did this...

```
yum install openssl openssl-devel pam-devel
wget ftp://ftp.cac.washington.edu/imap/imap-2007f.tar.gz
tar zxvf imap-2007f.tar.gz
```

Then I had to make a soft link so the compiler could find the libraries. In my case I did the following:

```
mkdir /usr/local/ssl
ln -s /usr/include /usr/local/ssl/include
```

and then compile:

```
cd imap-2007f
make lnp SSLTYPE=unix EXTRACFLAGS=-fPIC
```

Then I was able to compile PHP by adding the imap source path to the config param like so:

```
/path/to/php/src> ./configure ...other_params... '--with-imap=/path/to/imap-2007f' '--with-imap-ssl' 
make
make install
```

Comment: For Ubuntu I made imap-2007f with "make ldb".

Answer (score 5):

I've Installed the following package and it works :
**uw-imap-devel**


Run this command on CentOS 7.x : 
`yum -y install uw-imap-devel`

Answer (score 3):

Install imap before installing php.

> brew install imap-uw

then

> brew install php55 --with-fpm --with-imap  --without-apache
>   --with-debug

The --with-imap option should then run fine.