# Errors when installing IMAP extension on official PHP docker image

Tags: php, docker, imap

If you're installing the IMAP extension in your PHP docker image, it's possible that you get some errors like:

> configure: error: utf8_mime2text() has new signature, but
>   U8T_CANONICAL is missing. This should not happen. Check config.log for
>   additional information.

and then:

> configure: error: This c-client library is built with Kerberos
>   support.

Answer (score 24):

To solve this error:

> configure: error: utf8_mime2text() has new signature, but
>   U8T_CANONICAL is missing. This should not happen. Check config.log for
>   additional information.

You just need to run the next command:

```
apt update && apt install -y libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

So, now is probably that a new error appear:

> configure: error: This c-client library is built with Kerberos
>   support.

To solve this new error, you must install the extension with the next command:

```
docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl && docker-php-ext-install imap
```

Comment: I had some follow up issues caused by the `&& rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*` part. Just in case anyone else is unfamiliar with it: You can leave out that part as it isn't related to this issue in particular. You should read about the associated best practices e.g. [in the official docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#apt-get).