# Enabled IMAP on Docker but Imap are undefined?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, php-7.3

I came around this solution [52314179](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314179/errors-when-installing-imap-extension-on-official-php-docker-image/52314180) to install and enable imap on docker.

```
docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl && docker-php-ext-install imap
```

Then the imap is installed and enabled but upon using an imap function, an error occurred.

> Error: Call to undefined function imap_open()

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you forgot to restart the container.

Check it here.
[Link](https://serversforhackers.com/c/updating-containers)