# Compiling PHP5.5 from src code on centos failed

Tags: php, centos

I am trying to compile php with imap from its source code, but while running the following `configure` command:

```
./configure    \
--prefix=/opt/php5   \
--with-config-file-path=/opt/php5/etc   \
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/php5/etc/php.d   \
--with-curl   \
--with-gd   \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib64   \
--with-png-dir   \
--with-xpm-dir   \
--with-freetype-dir  \
--with-t1lib   \
--with-mcrypt   \
--with-mhash   \
--with-mysql   \
--with-mysqli   \
--with-pdo-mysql \
--with-openssl   \
--with-xsl   \
--with-bz2   \
--with-gettext   \
--with-pear   \
--with-zlib   \
--enable-exif  \
--enable-wddx   \
--enable-bcmath  \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-ftp   \
--enable-mbstring   \
--enable-soap   \
--enable-sockets   \
--enable-shmop   \
--enable-dba   \
--enable-sysvmsg  \
--enable-sysvsem   \
--enable-zip   \
--enable-sysvshm   \
--with-libdir=lib64   \
--with-xmlrpc  \
--enable-fpm  \
--with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr,12.1   \
--with-imap=/usr/local/imap/imap-2004g/  \
--with-imap-ssl \
--enable-pic \
--with-imap=/usr/local/imap-2004g/lib
```

it give the following error:

```
configure: error: utf8_mime2text() has new signature, but U8T_CANONICAL is missing. This should not happen. Check config.log for additional information.
```

I installed all required libraries for `utf8_mime2text` but same error kept occurring also tired the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436356/configure-error-utf8-mime2text-has-new-signature-but-u8t-canonical-is-missi)

```
Package uw-imap-devel-2007f-16.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

the `config.log` file show this that may be related:

```
configure:47265: checking for utf8_mime2text signature
configure:47287: cc -c -I  conftest.c >&5
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:47287: $? = 4
configure: failed program was:
```

OS: CentOS 7

Any advise?

Comment: **Danger**: PHP 5.5 is beyond end of life. It is not supported. It does not get security updates. Do not use it.

Comment: We aware of that, upgrade on plan, however I need the module working with php ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked to solved the issue by doing the following:

1- create new directory for imap

```
mkdir /usr/local/imap
```

2- downloaded client-c from [here](http://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/net/mail/imap/c-client.tar.gz) inside created directory by:

```
wget http://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/net/mail/imap/c-client.tar.gz
```

3- tar downloaded file:

```
tar -xvzf c-client.tar.gz
```

4- inide created directory `imap-227f` create two new directories like following:

```
mkdir lib
mkdir include
```

5- go to c-client source code

```
cd imap-2007f/src/c-client/
```

6- copy all the `*.h` files into `include/` and all the `*.c` files into `lib/`

```
cp *.h /usr/local/imap/imap-2007f/include/
cp *.c /usr/local/imap/imap-2007f/lib/
```

7- go to imap ext directory inside php, in my case was:

```
cd /usr/local/src/php-5.5.38/ext/imap
```

8- do `phpize`

9- install imap-devel for centos

```
sudo yum install uw-imap-devel
```

10- configure by doing:

```
./configure --with-libdir=lib64  --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl
```

11- do `make`

12- after make, it will give the directory to imap.so extension, if not, do:

```
find / -name imap.so
```

13- do `php -i | grep extension_dir` to find extensions directory of php, then copy the compiled extension to that directory:

```
cp .libs/imap.so /opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/
```

14- do `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'` to find the loaded `php.ini`, then add the new compiled extension to it `extension=imap.so`:

```
nano /opt/php5/etc/php.ini 
add: extension=imap.so
```

15- restart php, for php-fpm:

```
/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
```

in this case you will overcome following two errors:

```
configure: error: utf8_mime2text() has new signature, but U8T_CANONICAL
configure: error: Cannot find imap library (libc-client.a). Please check your c-client installation.
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the top:

```
$ cd /usr/local/
$ wget http://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/net/mail/imap/imap-2007f.tar.gz 
$ tar -xvzf imap-2007f.tar.gz
$ cd /imap-2007f
$ make lrh
```

`imap` should now be built... now adjust your `php` parameters in `./configure`:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/php5 --with-config-file-path=/opt/php5/etc --with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/php5/etc/php.d --with-curl --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib64 --with-png-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-freetype-dir --with-t1lib --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --with-openssl --with-xsl --with-bz2 --with-gettext --with-pear --with-zlib --enable-exif --enable-wddx --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --enable-ftp --enable-mbstring --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-shmop --enable-dba --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-zip --enable-sysvshm --with-xmlrpc --enable-fpm --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr,12.1 --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --with-imap=/usr/local/imap-2007f/ --with-imap-ssl --enable-pic --with-libdir=/usr/local/imap-2007f/lib/
```

> If you receive an error in `config.log` such as:

```
make: *** No rule to make target /usr/local/src/php-5.5.38/ext/imap/php_imap.c', needed by ext/imap/php_imap.lo'. Stop.
```

You're probably missing the `php_imap.c` file in the aforementioned directory. Once that's resolved then you should be able to successfully build your `php` with `imap`.

Comment: Thanks but library already installed as mentioned in the question. 
`Package uw-imap-devel-2007f-16.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`
I'll update the question with library name.

Comment: Yeah, you have the correct one, so it's odd you are experiencing that error.

Comment: That is the point, all required libraries there but the error is keep persisting.

Comment: How did you set up the `configure` file?

Comment: It was exist already with previously installed version, I am trying to add `imap` extension to it and recompile php with it.

Comment: @Eng7: You probably need to change your parameter `with-imap=/usr/local/imap/imap-2004g/` to be `with-imap=/usr/local/imap/imap-2007f/`...

Comment: But that directory not exist, why I should do that?

Comment: I would imagine that if you just installed `imap-2007f` you would want to use that one and not `imap-2004g`. Have you installed `libc-client-devel`? Do you have a directory at the following location: `/usr/local/imap-2007f`?

Comment: The libc-client-devel library installed, and the only one exist is `/usr/local/imap-2004g`

Comment: Try this one: https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/libc-client-2007f-16.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: `Package libc-client-2007f-16.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

Comment: Try `locate uw-imap-devel-2007f`... it should give you some insight into where it's installed.

Comment: Cant be located, not exist!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198224/discussion-between-lll-and-eng7).