# installing php-imap through dockerfile

Tags: php, dockerfile, imap, php-imap

I'm trying to run a new dockerfile build for a laravel app, and all I need to do is get imap for php installed through docker

I'm running this now:

```
FROM quay.io/appTest/docker-php-iaccess-odbc:7.3-prod

WORKDIR /docker_app

COPY ./ /docker_app


RUN set -ex                                                         && \
docker-php-ext-install imap                             

RUN set -ex                                                                                     && \
chmod -R a+w /docker_app/storage                                                            && \
cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini                         && \
composer install --no-progress --optimize-autoloader --no-scripts --no-interaction          && \
php artisan clear-compiled                                                                  && \
php artisan optimize                                                                        && \
php artisan config:clear
```

But when I build in command line I get thorugh that install imap step and get this error:

```
configure: error: utf8_mime2text() has new signature, but U8T_CANONICAL is missing. This should not happen. Check config.log for additional information.
```

I have no idea what's going on here, but how should I be installing php-imap through dockerfile?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38526260/1213708?

Comment: Ah, I had not! I just tried it and I think it may have worked